# How to Stream Data To an EMR Cluster

Tags: hadoop, logstash, amazon-emr

I appreciate ideas on how to stream data from an On-Premise Windows server to a persistent EMR cluster?

**Some Background**

I would like to run a persistent cluster running a MR job much like the WordCount examples that are available.  I would like to stream text from a local Windows Server up to the cluster and have it processed by the running job.

All of the streaming WordCount examples I have reviewed always start with a static text file in S3 and don't cover how to implement anything to generate the stream.

Does this need to be treated in two parts?

1. Get the data first into S3
2. Stream it into the EMR cluster?

I have seen tools like Logstash which tend to run agents on the local server which tail the end of a weblog and transfer it.

As you can probably tell, I'm a Windows guy, stretching into EMR and by association Linux.  Feel free to let me know if there is some way cool command line tool that already does this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually want to stream, or do you want to occasionally ship off log files?  Also:  The cluster is persistent, but is the Hadoop job?

Answer (score 0):

Currently EMR as-is only supports MR, Hive, Pig, HBase and Impala. MR/Hive/Pig process the data in a batch oriented fashion and data can't be streamed to them. While HBase is a NoSQL DB and Impala is used for interactive ad-hoc queries.

For processing streaming data there are a lot of other options like [Storm](http://storm-project.net/), [Samza](http://samza.incubator.apache.org/), [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/). From AWS there is [Kinesis](http://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) which has been moved into GA recently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a static file would go into S3 and then be the input into your EMR cluster job.
But I believe that fact you want a persistent cluster implies you are streaming in continuation from your Windows server. Is that the case ?
If so you need to create a AWS Kinesis Stream, configure your producers which put data into the stream's shards by calling the Putrecord.
Start by reading "[Developing Record Consumer Applications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-app.html)"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use apache Flume (https://flume.apache.org/)

> Flume is a distributed, reliable, and available service for efficiently collecting, aggregating, and moving large amounts of log data. It has a simple and flexible architecture based on streaming data flows. It is robust and fault tolerant with tunable reliability mechanisms and many failover and recovery mechanisms. It uses a simple extensible data model that allows for online analytic application.